# How to distort a generated node (not image) without using compositing?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, 2d, distort

[image: How to distort this shape to make it move like a tadpole?]

How to distort this shape to make it move like a tadpole without using compositing?
I know that for image textures we can use wave texture to distort it and get a ripple effect.
But what about this generated shape? Any help is appreciated!

Here is the blender file:
[droplet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v6dp5JGLla8BdBXqRkMBKzS_tI4qD8L9/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: you mean you already have this image and you want to find a way to distort it? Maybe share your file so that we can give a try? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots I've already added the blender file. It would be so kind if you or anyone else could take a look!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apologies.. I felt I had to make a tadpole with a longer tail to illustrate.

You can distort a procedural texture in exactly the same way as you would distort an image texture: by distorting the whole space containing it.

[image]

*The straight object space, XY > RG, and the procedural texture made in it*

This is a straight tadpole: it was constructed as a set of functions and masks of ordinary Object space, because I thought it was easier to have 0 in the middle, but it could have been UV, or Generated space, shifted a bit, depending on how you want the space to behave.

To put, say, a wobble into the tail, you can manipulate the coordinates that the tadpole-making part of the tree uses, *before* you start making the tadpole, just as you might manipulate your given UV coordinates, *before* giving them to an Image texture to tell it where in the image to find a color.

[image]

*The part of the tree which distorts the space, and f(X) as greyscale, which will be added to Y*

To put a wobble into the Y of the procedural texture depending on X, you come up with some function of X that you can add to the Y coordinate, before handing the Y on to tadpole-making. Supposing it was just Y => Y + sin(X), that would put a sine-distortion in Y along the entire length of X, and you might have to mask off the head, to stop it being distorted, along with the tail.

This chunk of tree is just a more controlled version of that - it so happens it doesn't need a mask, because raising a negative number to a fractional power results in 0. The power also crunches the wave horizontally as the X goes positive. (Note our original Object X is multiplied by a negative before giving it to the power function, so positive X is then on the left)

[image]

*The distorted space, and the resulting distorted tadpole*

**TL;DR**
This is what happens to the Object space when the grey f(X) bands are added to its Y .. and the resulting distortion of the tadpole,when built using the X and Y's of the new space.

As you can see from the green value-field in the tree, you can keyframe the phase of the sine-function to animate the tail and move the head up and down, all in one.

[image]

[image]

Comment: And that, kids, is how life began... With the original sin(x). In a blender.

Comment: @Jachym Yes while making this, I could swear I heard the pitter-patter of tiny Default Cubes..

Comment: Wow! Wow!! Super AWESOME! Man you are genius!! And a great THANK YOU for the detailed explanation and the clarity!!